# Call a function when i click outside to the element like boot strap modal get closed

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-show

I have created a popup box of div. Which get shown when i click on an icon and get hide when i click on close button. But i want to get it closed if click out side of the popup. What i can do for that. I am using angular in my project and ng-show and ng-hide to show and hide the div. Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance.
html code

```
<p ng-click="openPopUP()">openPopUp</p>

<div ng-show="popup">
<p>helo</p>
<p ng-click="closePopUp()">Close</p>
</div>
```

Java script

```
$scope.openPopUP = function(){
$scope.popup = true;
}
$scope.closePopUp= function(){
$scope.popup = false;
}
```

I just want to close if some one click out side the div

Comment: please use angular ui modal popups

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i can but its according to the project requirement so i can't.

Answer (score -1):

In your controller:

```
 angular.element(document.body).on('click', function() {
     $scope.$apply(function() {
         $scope.closePopUp();
     });
 });
```

Comment: Its working but the problem is that it get closed if i clicked on popup div as well as its in the body context as well.

Answer (score -1):

First of all read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element?rq=1) post to get an idea how to close popups.

Fix for @pixelbits solution is to add ***$event.stopPropagation();*** on popup div.

**HTML**

```
<p ng-click="openPopUP()">openPopUp</p>

<div ng-show="popup" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">
<p>helo</p>
<p ng-click="closePopUp()">Close</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.element(document.body).on('click', function() {
     $scope.$apply(function() {
         $scope.closePopUp();
     });
 });

$scope.openPopUP = function(){
 $scope.popup = true;
}
$scope.closePopUp= function(){
 $scope.popup = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Waqas but it won't work because for every click we are clicking the body context and it will never make the popup to be showed, as with this code we are closing the popup always. Hope you got ma point.